# Replacing SharePoint toxic serves - Guidelines?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-farm

I am working on replacing toxic servers(Windows 2008 R2) with new servers Windows 2012 R2. Below are the steps I completed.

We are not replacing DB sever as it already Windows 2012 R2. Im only replacing 2 Web servers, 1 App server and 1 search server. Following are the steps I did till now.

1. Installing preqs and SP 2013 in new severs
2. Made new sever as same patch level of the existing servers
3. Running PS Config in new severs to add them to current farm connecting to current config DB.
4. Setting search topology with new servers.

My next step is to change the load balancer pointing to new web servers - Before Im doing that I just want to know If there anything else that I should be alert on. My few worries are below. Please guide me.

- What about hosted custom applications(webparts) in the farm
- Layout folder and master pages?
- InfoPath form templates in CA?
- Other things that I should care about while replacing servers.

My question is, would all above thing automatically transferred to new severs on  adding servers to new farm/enabling services? Or What are the steps I should perform additionally to make new farm exactly same as the old one.

Any help/blog would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll also want to start the appropriate Service Instances and [modify the Search topology](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/search/change-the-default-search-topology) to move them to the new server(s).

Any content related items, InfoPath templates, custom webparts, etc. you don't need to worry about. Any custom WSPs will auto deploy on the new server as you join it or start the necessary services. InfoPath forms in CA are stored in the Administration database.

Now if you've made any *manual* modifications (which you shouldn't) to the web.config of a Web App or manually copied anything into the Hive, yes you'll have to perform those operations manually on the new server(s), as well.